# Adding to multidimensional array from foreach loop issue

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, foreach

I have a foreach loop that iterates through posts and performs actions (such as setting a `$distance` variable for each). Through a conditional, it needs to do **two things**, which work independently but I cannot get them to work together.

`$results[] = $value;` works, as it adds the array (`$value`)

`$results['distance'] = $distance;` works by itself but I need to include the `$value` arrays.

If I have them both in, it results in twice as many arrays as there should be. Distance is supposed to be included in the value. If I do an `array_push` it works also, but I need to specify the key.

```
foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
  $loop->the_post();
  $result_lat = get_post_meta( $value->ID, 'latitude', true );
  $result_long = get_post_meta( $value->ID, 'longitude', true );
  $distance = round(calc_distance($input_lat, $input_lng, $result_lat, $result_long, "M"));

  // add item to results if within distance
  if ($distance < $_GET['within']) {
    $results[] = $value;
    $results['distance'] = $distance; // add distance to array
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a single multidimensional array to store values:

```
foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
    #..
    $results[$key]["values"] = $value;  
    $results[$key]["distance"] = $distance;
}
#show first row
print_r( array_values($results)[0] );
#iterate
foreach ($results as $r_key => $r_value) {
    print_r($r_value["distance"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Distance is supposed to be included in the value

Well then why don’t you just do exactly that – put `$distance` into `$value`, before you put `$value` into the `$results` array?

```
$value['distance'] = $distance;
$results[] = $value;
```

Comment: Thanks, and I see the logic, but this code broke the page